# How to typehint context in an IDE?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, phpdoc

I am using `Closure::call` (http://php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php) to call an external closure inside a class context.

Here's a simple repro:

```
class Foo {
    private $bar = 'baz';

    /**
     * Executes a closure in $this context and returns whatever the closure returns.
     *
     * @param \Closure $closure
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function callClosureInThisContext(\Closure $closure) {
        return $closure->call($this);
    }
}

class Closures {
    /**
     * @return \Closure
     */
    public function getClosureForFoo() : \Closure {
        return function () {
            // how do I tell my IDE that in this context $this is actually class Foo,
            // and not the class Closures?
            print $this->bar;
        };
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$closures = new Closures();
$foo->callClosureInThisContext($closures->getClosureForFoo()); // prints "baz"
```

This works as expected, but my IDE is of course, not happy, and is warning me about the "field `bar` not found":
[image]

Can I somehow tell the IDE (in this case PhpStorm) that the closure is going to be used inside another class and that it should assume its context?

Comment: As suggested on the [forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000630450-How-to-typehint-context-) -- file new ticket to the [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI). Currently IDE cannot suppress the warning here / override with typehint.

Comment: It seems this may not be possible. I've filled a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38536

Comment: Please provide code sample + screenshot of current behaviour in actual ticket -- not just "have a look at this SO question/forum thread" text.

Comment: @LazyOne ~~okay will do~~ done

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/** @var $this Foo */
print $this->bar;
```

It will add autocomplete for class Foo additionally to Closure

Comment: I've already tried this, it doesn't work, because the property is not public, so the IDE complains about accessing something with protected/private access.