# Is there a PhpDoc annotation for redefining $this in a re-bound Closure?

Tags: php, binding, annotations, closures, phpdoc

This comes up in Laravel a lot if you use [Macros](https://laravel-news.com/relationship-macros), but it's not exclusive to that. If you [bind](https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) a closure to another object context, the nature of `$this` within the closure changes. But IDEs don't recognize that, and don't offer the appropriate auto-fill options. It still thinks the context is that of the class the closure is defined in.

I know that most IDEs will respect the `@var` annotation, but in this case, for PhpStorm at least, that doesn't seem to stick past the first subsequent use of `$this`.

For exanple:

```
class AppServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Relation::macro('setMorphTables', function ($foreignPivotTypeField, $relatedPivotTypeField = null) {
            $parentModel = $this->getParent();
            $currentTable = $this->getTable()
        });
    }
}
```

The code works of course, but when I type the `->`, the IDE's auto-fill suggestions are for the AppServiceProvider class, not the Relation class.

If I add `/** @var MorphToMany $this */` to override the IDEs assumptions (which works as expected on normal variables), the suggestions *are* corrected, but *only* for the first use of `$this`. The second one reverts back to listing AppServiceProvider options, unless I place that annotation before *each* use of `$this`.

So, is there a more proper way to annotate the new definition of `$this`, or is this just a shortcoming of PhpStorm?

Comment: [Relevant PhpStorm issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38536). Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894614/how-to-typehint-context-in-an-ide).

Comment: Hm, shortcoming of the IDE then. Oh well. Thanks a lot for digging that up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually surprised `@var Type @this` only affects the following line, as it does not for normal variables. Seems inconsistent for no reason.